# Merge GPS Data to MP4 Export of GoPro 360 format

Tags: gps, gopro

Is there a way to merge gps data and original Go Pro 360 file format to a reframed exported version of the same—but MP4 (same time start/stop).

- I can use the GoPro to reframe.
- I can extract the telemetry.

I don’t need to overlay the data in a new video but want to embed the “metadata” or gps exif data for each frame (or maybe a frame every one second) into a single MP4.

Is this doable at all? Thanks

-Scott

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? "Is this possible" sorts of questions usually don't demonstrate much effort on the part of the one asking, and are also typically answered correctly with a "yes" or "no", when we can probably assume you actually want to know HOW to do this, and not simply whether or not it is possible. Please take the time to EDIT your question with this in mind, and tell us what you've tried while you're at it.

Comment: To break your problem down, assuming you do want to know how: you need to know how to add metadata to individual frames or other time-specific spaces of an MP4 file, and then you need to know how to get this GPS data into a format that can be stored. Also, you may consider another, more flexible, container for your video, if MP4 doesn't have quite the features you're looking for.